# trying to decrypt a file using a key

Tags: c++, encryption

I am able to encrypt and decrypt a message using this key: string key = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba"; without any issue, but I wanted to use a more complex key instead.  This is the key that I'm using now: string key = "zwtqnkhebyvspmjgdaxurolifc";

The message is encrypted as expected, but when I try and decrypt it the message isn't returned to it's normal state.  Below is the code:

```
string Security::DecWordUsingCrypto(string word, string key)
{
  string decWord = word;

  for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++)
    {
      char c = tolower(word[i]);

      if ((c < 'a') || (c > 'z'))
          decWord[i] = c;
      else
        {
          decWord[i] = key[(c - 'a')]; 
        }
    }
 return decWord;
}
```

I know why my message is being encrypted further, but I don't know how to decrypt it without an error.  I can't simply state `int j = (c + 'a')`. Any suggestions on what I could try?

Comment: Any chance you can explain what you get, vs. what you expect?

Comment: Instead of using magic numbers (like `97` and `122`) it's easier to read and understand what you do if you use the actual letters those ASCII codes represent (i.e. `'a'` and `'z'`).

Comment: What is the encryption function? I'm afraid you are using `output[i]=key[input[i]-'a']` in both functions which wouldn't work for an arbitrary key. One of the functions must perform lookup in the key.

Comment: Comments should not say what you are doing (the code does that) they should explain why you are doing it.

Comment: Also, are you sure you're using the same `key` for both encryption and decryption?

Comment: What happens is the message is only further encrypted.  This is the original message: I really hope that this works well.  After encryption: b anzssf ejgn uezu uebx ljavx lnss.
When I decrypt, this is what I get:  w zmcxxk nyhm rncr rnwi syzoi smxx.

Comment: I am positive that it's the same key.  I just copy and pasted.

Comment: Did you notice that the encryption and decryption methods are identical?  How do you expect them to do opposite things?

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that.  When I was using a different key, it worked.  I've been trying several other things in my decryption function to no avail.

Comment: @Inspired - I have tried using output[i] = key[input[i] + 'a' as wel, but it doesn't do the opposite.

Comment: Maybe you should actually THINK about what you're doing.  Work through it on paper.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're using a simple substitution cipher, with your 'key' being a permutation of a-z?  If that's the case, I would guess that your problem is that you are trying to use the same permutation for both encode and decode (the code you have above), which only works if your permutation is reflexive (which your first z-a permutation is, but your second is not).

In order to decode something encoded with a non-reflexive permutation, you need to find the reverse permutation:

```
string reverse_perm(string key) {
    assert(key.size() == 26);  // 26 letters in the alphabet
    string rv(26, '\0');
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        char c = key[i];
        assert(islower(c));        // must be a lower case letter
        assert(rv[c-'a'] == '\0'); // each letter only appears once in the key
        rv[c-'a'] = 'a'+i;
    }
    return rv;
}
```

So if you encode with `key`, you can decode with `reverse_perm(key)`.  You can test if a key is reflexive (same key for both encode and decode) with `key == reverse_perm(key)`

Comment: I wouldn't have known to do anything like that.  What is `string rv(26, '\0')` stating?  I know rv is a string, I'm just wondering what the parameter is implying.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII: This initializes the string `rv` to a size of 26 characters, all of which are NUL (`'\0'`) characters.

Comment: I just mapped everything out, and now I understand what is going on. It essentially creates a reverse key to be used as a reference in my decrypt function.  That's brilliant.

Comment: @KevinSimpsonII - No, that's simple thought.  Try it.